# I need help about the LoL minions(And structures)

Tags: league-of-legends

So I've seen videos on YouTube of LoL by people such as Keyori, Dunkey, SivHD, AnTrollingNoob, etc., and in some videos, something about the minions and structures is different. In their gameplay, the minions are the opposite color that they're supposed to be. For example, when you're in the red team, the color of the minions and structures is blue, when it's supposed to be red. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot of a League of Legends game with reversed colors]

I believe the game is designed that way, but I want to know if it's possible to make it the way its supposed to be.

Comment: Do you happen to have a picture of what it is you're talking about?

Comment: Perhaps they are uploading a replay of their match? I know for dota spectator mode the jungle creeps have a purple-ish health bar while when actually playing they have a red bar like any other opponent.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a441e52714377e5cf2edf8780b612f53

Comment: As you see in the photo (Which is taken from a video from Dunkey) Dunkey is on the red team and the minion's color is the way its supposed to be

Answer (score 12):

It is an option in the settings menu.

You can set it so that bottom side will always be blue and top side will always be red. Or you can set it so that allied minions are always blue, and the enemies are always red.

Answer (score 0):

It's an option in the setting menu to either make the color differentiation relative to the side of the map your team occupies, or consistent geographically.